# Build a json file with Jobject with name

Tags: c#, json.net

Hi I have the following sample json

```
{
    "PropertyOne": "PropOne",
    "PropertyTwo": "PropTwo",
    "PropertyThree": "PropThree"
}
```

and I need to convert into below by amending it how do you do it?

```
{
    "MyObject": {
        "PropertyOne": "PropOne",
        "PropertyTwo": "PropTwo",
        "PropertyThree": "PropThree"
    }
}
```

I did

```
var tempJson= JObject.Parse(origJson);
tempJson.Name="MyObject" ; //Name does not exists
```

any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your original json is a string an you just need to wrap it in MyObject you can just use a format to write a new string

```
var tempJson = $"{{\"MyObject\":{origJson}}}";
```

Comment: Hi that is exactly what I need .I need to wait few mins before I can accept. what about joining the 2 samples in my question to be a single json file with 2 sections

Answer (score 0):

Without resorting to string formatting, you can do it like this:

```
var newJson = new JObject(new JProperty("MyObject", JObject.Parse(origJson))).ToString();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oX8erE